# Adding an object to NSMutableArray - weird behaviour

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am facing a very weird issue. I create an object and I add it to a NSMutableArray but when I try to read it after I insert it, some subclasses of the object change to some weird classes like

> PINGIFAnimatedImageManager

Here is the code I use to create the object and insert it to the NSMutableArray:

```
CustomContentGridRow *row = [[CustomContentGridRow alloc]init];
row.child1 = [dataManager getMapLocation]; // This is the MapLocation object that will change to this weird PINGIFAnimatedImageManager
row.useFullWidth=1;
row.index=0;
[arrCustomChilds addObject:row];
```

This is the CustomContentGridRow class:

```
@interface CustomContentGridRow : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) MapLocation *child1;
@property (nonatomic, assign) MapLocation *child2;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int useFullWidth;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int index;

@end
```

So when I put a breakpoint at this line `[arrCustomChilds addObject:hotelRow];`, when I read the `row` object I get the expected results. But when I place a breakpoint after the above code to read the `arrCustomChilds` the class of child1 changes to some weird classes. Also, sometimes it won't change to another class but it will give nil values.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: You should change property modifier from "assign" to "strong" for class objects.

Comment: what is `arrCustomChilds`?

Comment: @kirander Yeap that's the answer. Please write it so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change property modifier from "assign" to "strong" for class objects. Otherwise undefined behaviour can happen.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode -> Product -> Scheme - edit Scheme. Check the settings of RUN mode. If it is Release change to Debug.

This will give you the correct values

Change below properties

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MapLocation *child1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) MapLocation *child2;
```

assign to strong

Comment: He's talking about breakpoins therefore obviously he is running in Debug.

Comment: You can add breakpoints in release mode too. But you wont see proper results as it is not a debug mode

Answer (score 0):

Your interface should be:

```
@interface CustomContentGridRow : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) MapLocation *child1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) MapLocation *child2;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int useFullWidth;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int index;

@end
```

the class objects should be strong not assign